# Monadic version of .~ (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'm looking for a version of `.~` that takes a value wrapped in a Monad and returns a Monad. For example:

`(0, 1) & _1 .~ 100 = (100,1)`

Hypothetical `.~~` would:

`(0, 1) & _1 .~~ return 100 = return (100,1)`

While it would not be hard to define, is it already defined somewhere in the Lens package?

Comment: I don't believe that operator exists in lens already, but you could define something similar as `(.~~) = liftM3 (.~)`.  But all of its arguments have to be monadic, so you could do `return (0, 1) & return _1 .~~ return 100`.  It'd probably be better to define it with a `do` block as `(.~~) l m x = do { v <- m; return $ x & l .~ v }`.

Comment: A more general form would be with `fmap` as `(.~~) l m x = fmap ((x &) . (l .~)) m`, and it's shorter, too.  Testing it as `(0, 1) & _1 .~~ Just 1` returns `Just (1, 1)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about a *single* operator precisely like that, but with some "tiny" adjustments, this is essentially what the *raw* application of a lens does.  The adjustments are:

- You use a modifying function rather than just a setting value.
- Your `Monad` needs to be a `Functor`, as nearly all are. (This will be mandatory from GHC 7.10, but isn't quite yet in 7.8.)

So you can do:

```
Prelude Control.Lens> (0,1) & _1 (const (Just 100))
Just (100,1)
Prelude Control.Lens> (0,1) & _1 (const [100])
[(100,1)]
Prelude Control.Lens> (0,1) & _1 (const [100,200])
[(100,1),(200,1)]
```

Even works with `Traversals`:

```
Prelude Control.Lens> (0,1) & both (const [100,200])
[(100,100),(100,200),(200,100),(200,200)]
```

If you still want an operator too, the `%%~` operator has been defined, but it's essentially a type-restricted synonym for `id`:

```
Prelude Control.Lens> (0,1) & _1 %%~ const (return 100) :: Either () (Int,Int)
Right (100,1)
```

Finally, although you *did* say it was simple, your `.~~` operator (which I think would logically be `.%~` or the like if it were actually in `lens`) can be defined as just

```
Prelude Control.Lens> let (.~~) = (. const)
Prelude Control.Lens> (0,1) & _1 .~~ return 100 :: Either () (Int,Int)
Right (100,1)
```